# Angular click event not working with array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="options-wrapper">
  <div *ngFor="let option of options" class="option" (click)="selectOption()">
    {{ option.label }}
  </div>
</div>
```

with the following component class:

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  Output,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'mdj-select-list',
  templateUrl: './select-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-list.component.scss'],
})
export class SelectListComponent {
  @Input()
  options: { label: string, value: string }[] = [];

  selectedOption: string;

  selectOption() {
    console.log('click');
  }
}
```

For some reason, I have to click the div twice in order to make the `selectOption()` function run. This only seems to happen when I pass in an array of objects. If I pass in an array of strings, it works as expected.

Comment: how about if you wrap your `option.label` in a proper HTML element, like a `ul`>`li`? Why do you want the text to be inside the div? seems like a bad HTML structure

Comment: @Andres2142 that doesn't make any difference with my original issue.

Comment: The event should be indexed. It should be one level down in your HTML structure pointing the element from the list in the DOM not to the whole list

Comment: please add the code where you set the input data

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your code in a [stackblitz instance](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ikb9ga?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmdj.component.html) and it seems that I'm not getting the same behavior that you get. I get logged every click without having to click twice. Check if there is any difference between my code and yours (excepting file names and the fact that I did not add a styles file).